# Why am I getting a wrong prediction values when using statsmodels.formula.api / statsmodels.api in Python?

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, predict

I'm trying to get the prediction values of a Simple Linear Regression model created with Stats models in Python. I get the next results of the model:

```
Intercept      0.2750
SAT            0.0017
```

So my logic is, the linear regression equation should be `Y = 0.275 + 0.0017*x`

If I pass the next values `SAT = [1700, 1670]`, `Y` results should be `~ 3.165, 3.114`
But I'm getting `3.089710, 3.040039`

Do I have a missconception of how the `predict()` method works or is there something wrong in my code? Any help would be well apreciated, I tried to find anython on google but nothing near. Thanks in advance to everyone!

Here's the head of the dataset I'm using and the block of the python code

```
#Creating the model
dataset = pd.read_csv('1.01. Simple linear regression.csv')

print(dataset.head())
    SAT   GPA
0  1714  2.40
1  1664  2.52
2  1760  2.54
3  1685  2.74
4  1693  2.83

reg_exp = 'GPA ~ SAT'
ols_model_results = smf.ols(formula=reg_exp, data=dataset).fit()

print(ols_model_results.params)
Intercept    0.275040
SAT          0.001656


#Making predictions
new_data = pd.DataFrame({'Intercept': 1, 'SAT': [1700, 1670]})
predictions = ols_model_results.predict(new_data)
print(predictions)
0  3.089710
1  3.040039
```

Answer (score 0):

The OLS parameters as printed have likely been rounded to 6 decimal places, and the results that you share at the beginning of your question you have been further rounded to 4 decimal places.

The largest source of discrepancy between the `predict()` function results and your hand calculation is coming from your rounding of the coefficient for SAT. Even though you've only changed it by roughly 0.00005 (which looks really small), when multiplied by values in the thousands (like SAT scores), the error propagates:

```
1700*0.0017 - 1700*0.001656 = 1700*(0.0017 - 0.001656)
                            = 1700*0.000044
                            = 0.0748
```

This is about what you get when looking at the difference in your result and the result from `predict()`. The function will be more precise than any hand calculations you do from the rounded output.